# Compiler scope values in qmake

Tags: c++, qt, scope, qmake

qmake provides several built-in platform scopes, allowing a project file to perform different operations depending on the current platform:

```
win32 {
    ...
}
unix {
    ...
}
```

All platform specifications in the `mkspecs` directory can also be used to test various platform/compiler combination, e.g.

```
linux-g++ {
    ...
}
win32-g++ {
    ...
}
win32-msvc2003 {
    ...
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to test only the compiler (without the os)

```
#This does not work
g++ {
    ...
}
msvc {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to list all combinations (`linux-g++ | win32-g++ | cygwin-g++ | ... {}`)? If this is not possible, is there a good reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You can do it like this:**

```
*-g++ {
    ...
}
win32-msvc* {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is even better to use `*-g++*`, to account for `*g++-32`, `*g++-64` and the likes (even though these specifications include the corresponding `*g++`, the scope conditional is not verified otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

These build in platform scopes are based on the [qmake spec](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#platform-scope-values) in Qt installation directory. The way platform scopes are resolved is not documented, but it seems that [qmake internally use regexes](https://github.com/Blizzard/qt/blob/master/qmake/project.cpp#L1562) to determine if the scope apply to the current `mkspecs`.

Only [wildcard matching](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#wildcard-matching) is enabled (ie `?`, `*`, `[]`)

Note that inside qmake `unix`,`win32`, `macx` have several meanings, both as magic keywords, and as a regular expressions to match.