# qmake: handling options for both gcc and msvc

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, g++, qmake

I would like to make a project file that would work both with msvc and gcc.

For instances, to optimize for speed you would do `cl /O2` and `g++ -O3`.

But I don't know how to tell the project file to make the difference. I would like something like :

```
msvc:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /O2 /openmp /arch:AVX
else:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O3 -march=native -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL
```

which doesn't work sadly.

Other way would be to change the mkspecs and bundle the new ones with my app, but it is not very portable.
Thanks !

Comment: What is the problem? What do you mean by saying 'it doesn't work sadly'?

Comment: Have you tried using a scope like `win32` and `!win32` like described in the docs?  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html

Comment: If I add the code I put before in my project file, I will still have : `cl -O3 -march=native -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL` while I want  `cl /O2 /openmp /arch:AVX`

Comment: And I don't wand a OS based scoping because MinGW might be used on windows.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Strange. I've just made a simple .pro file containing the 2 lines from your question and added another line: `message($${QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE})`. When I run qmake I get this: `Project MESSAGE: -O2 -MD /O2 /openmp /arch:AVX` which is fine because my environment is Win7 + MSVC2010. What is your environment?

Comment: Hmm. Weird. I guess I should had run qmake one or two times more just to be sure, because now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jean, to be precise, you should use this based on your description:

```
msvc:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /O2 /openmp /arch:AVX
gcc:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O3 -march=native -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL
```

Comment: right ! Is there a list of the compiler defines somewhere ? Like if one day I want to use clang ? (even if I think that the options are compatible with gcc, isn't it ?)

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier: Yes, you are right: At least for now, Clang tries to have options compatible with gcc, so there should be no problems as long as you don't use any exotic options... ;)

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier: And according your first question: I've been looking for a compiler scope list for qmake now for a couple of minutes (I needed it as well) but couldn't find anything :/ but by trial-and-error I found that MinGW simply is "mingw" (so quite the same as "gcc" and "msvc" -> easy to guess); So for clang I'm quite confident it's "clang" ;) EDIT: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523148/compiler-scope-values-in-qmake

Comment: @mozzbozz: off-topic, but you could look for the QMAKE_COMPILER variables in mkspecs. By the way, "mingw" seems to be a platform, not compiler, but yes, it will work. QMAKE_PLATFORM is the keyword in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project file I have been using.  It works for Windows (msvc) and Linux (gcc)

```
QT = core gui widgets

HEADERS += \
    render.h

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    render.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2

win32 { # For Windows
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -openmp
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -arch:AVX
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O2
}

linux { # For Linux
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
  QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mavx
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O3
}
```

Comment: Hmm, how is this better than the original post? Also, you do not need core and gui for the QT variable. They are included by default!

Comment: Well for one the OP said his post was not working.  I guess there was no problem.  But I tried your example.  It does not work for me.  I have to add to GCC `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp` otherwise I get a bunch of linker errors (`error: undefined reference to omp_get_num_threads` and so forth).

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you cannot use it to distinguish between MinGW and MSVC for example...

Comment: @mozzbozz, okay but the accepted answer still won't work with GCC unless `-fopenmp` is added to the LFLAGS. In any case I have moved on from qmake and use cmake instead now with qtcreator.

Comment: @Zboson: Well, you add fopenmp to the "linux" scope instead, what's the problem with it? But anyway, a combination of both is probably what one would need in "real world" circumstances. And I also though about switching to cmake sometimes as qmake lacks a few features... (and the documentation sometimes is horrible) However that would need a lot of time to figure everything out again, so it'll have to wait until I'm bored at some point ;)

Comment: @mozzbozz, gcc requires `-fopenmp` to compile and link.